# How to set variables inside a mocha test

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js

I am having trouble understanding how to set variables for use in my tests. For example I have a function called spark.isTriple() that takes a number and looks at an array called dice and returns true if the value occurs three or more times or false if it doesn't.

```
#In game.coffee

window.spark =  
  isTriple: (n)->        
    triples = _.filter dice, (i)->
      n is i
    if triples.length >= 3
      true
    else
      false
```

And I have a test that looks like this.

```
# In game_spec.coffee

describe 'spark.isTriple', ->
  it "Should return true if the given value is found 3 or more times in the dice roll", ->
    dice = [1,2,2,2,4,5]
    spark.isTriple(2).should.be.true
```

The problem is that 'dice' is also being set in an earlier test that is actually testing a rollDice() function. In that test dice is being set to a random array of values which is what it should be doing and testing. But for this particular test I want to be able to set 'dice' to a specific array in order to test my isTriple() function. I've tried placing the "dice = [1,2,2,2,3,4]" in a before() call and a beforeEach() call but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

If anyone can give me some help or pointers on this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna disagree with Peter here. I think depending on a variable across tests is a bad idea -- it sets you up for intermittent and weird failures in tests. Anything that's going to change as a result of the test should be contained only in that test. To that end, I'd write your re-write your code like so (from the coffee console):

```
window.spark = hasTriple: (dice, n) ->
  ld.filter(dice, ((i) -> n is i)).length >= 3 
{ hasTriple: [Function] }
coffee> window.spark.hasTriple([1,2,1,2,5,6], 2) 
false
coffee> window.spark.hasTriple([1,2,2,2,5,6], 2) 
true
```

I renamed _ to `ld` (aka Lodash) because `_` has a special meaning in the console so I think it's a good practice to avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks @jcollum. I ended up moving on and found myself needing to pass the dice array directly to isTriple anyway and so that worked out. I'm not sure if Peters answer would've worked or not, but I think I agree with what you're saying here. This feels cleaner aka safer. Much thanks.

Comment: @jcollum generally agree but it is common and clean (IMHO) to have a shared variable configured by a beforeEach and then a separate test for each aspect of that shared variable. That's pretty much the only time I have non-constant variables across a `describe` block.

Comment: @PeterLyons yeah you're right, but I generally reserve those sort of things for test setup/tear down variable (stubs etc). The isTriple code that he had looked like it was heading for Law of Demeter troubles so I pulled that reference to the outer variable out.

Answer (score 2):

So mocha + coffeescript sometimes requires an explicit declare in the right scope if you want a variable that a whole suite of tests can use and can be manipulated during before/beforeEach/after/afterEach.

```
describe 'spark.isTriple', ->
  dice = null #force coffeescript var declaration
  it "should blah blah", ->
    dice = [1,2,2,2,4,5]
```

I'm pretty sure something along those lines will fix your problem, but if you post a full file that demonstrates the issue I can be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter. I ended up refactoring the function as it were anyway, but I'll keep your suggestion in mind moving forward if run into a similar situation again.